# Strange Output in using SkipWhile() in LINQ

Tags: c#, linq

I was trying to workout the below example but get strange output for SkipWhile() operation it is not showing the expected output. Could some one explain why?

```
        List<Employees> emp = new List<Employees>();
        emp.Add(new Employees() { EmpId = 1, DeptId = 1, Salary = 20000 });
        emp.Add(new Employees() { EmpId = 2, DeptId = 2, Salary = 1000 });
        emp.Add(new Employees() { EmpId = 3, DeptId = 1, Salary = 3000 });
        emp.Add(new Employees() { EmpId = 4, DeptId = 3, Salary = 5000 });
        emp.Add(new Employees() { EmpId = 5, DeptId = 2, Salary = 4000 });


        var hsal = emp.OrderByDescending(x => x.Salary).GroupBy(x => x.DeptId).Select(x => x.FirstOrDefault());
        var secS = hsal.SkipWhile(x => x.Salary < 19000);
        foreach (Employees x in secS)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Employer {0} of Dept {1} gets {2} as salary", x.EmpId, x.DeptId, x.Salary);
        }
```

The output I get is, but it should not produce any results since it has to skip the salary when it is less that 19000.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The output looks correct to me.

The first item has a salary of 20000, which is not less than 19000.

Therefore the `SkipWhile()` skips nothing, because the predicate for the first item is false.

Thus, the entire list is returned in the foreach.

Comment: The first record does not satisfy the condition while the other records do satisfy the condition. Then why the satisfied records are not skipped in the output?

Comment: @Venkat [Read the documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb549075.aspx). `Returns: An IEnumerable<T> that contains the elements from the input sequence starting at the first element in the linear series that does not pass the test specified by predicate.`

Answer (score 2):

`SkipWhile` does not skip *all* elements with the given condition but only all until this condition is met. If you want to skip all use `Where`:

```
var secS = hsal.Where(x => x.Salary >= 19000);
```

Output (why *"should it not produce any results", there is one with salary=20000 ?)*:

```
Employer 1 of Dept 1 gets 20000 as salary
```